# Unpermitted parameter in Rails 4 when submitted nested attributes, has_many associated form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested-forms, strong-parameters

I have two models (`lead` which `has_many :quote_metals` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :quote_metals` and `quote_metal` which `belongs_to :lead`).

I am trying to write the information submitted in the form to the different datatables. There should just be one lead and multiple (no exact number) of quote_metals. I am receiving an error saying that `Unpermitted parameter: quote_metal`.

Here are the parameters:

```
Processing by LeadsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"h5iBI7teODFFXRk91puydlr4UmC9EhU5aR9ul2D0u4STFp68GV0wOgb/I43Ukga2MHjLWg1ZnbPeLwuLmMxrkw==", "lead"=>{"name"=>"Biggie", "email"=>"test@test.com",...., "note"=>"asdf", "quote_metal"=>[{"metal"=>"iron", "weight"=>"1", "unit"=>"pounds"}, {"metal"=>"ore", "weight"=>"4", "unit"=>"KG"}]}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Here is my controller:

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController

      def index
        @lead = Lead.new
        @quote_metal = @lead.quote_metals.build
      end

      def create
        #raise params.inspect
        @lead = Lead.create!(lead_params)
      end

      def show
      end


private

    def lead_params
      params.require(:lead).permit([:name, :email, :phone, :zip, :note, :method, quote_metals_attributes: [:id, :metal, :weight, :unit, :price]])
    end

end
```

Here is the form:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <%= form_for @lead, class: 'form-horizontal' do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :phone %>
          <%= f.telephone_field :phone, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :zip %>
          <%= f.text_field :zip, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :method %><br>
            <%= f.select :method, Lead.methods.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, k] }, {},
            class: "form-control", :required => true %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :notes %>
          <%= f.text_area :note, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

          <%= render :partial => "metalLead", locals: {f: f} %>
          <%= render :partial => "metalLead", locals: {f: f} %>

        <div class="form-group text-center">
          <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the partial:

```
<%= f.fields_for 'quote_metal[]', @quote_metal do |ff| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                  <%= ff.label :metal %><br>
                  <%= ff.select :metal, QuoteMetal.metals.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, k] }, {},
                  class: "form-control", :required => true %>
            </div>
          <!-- break -->
              <div class="form-group">
                  <%= ff.label :weight %><br>
                  <%= ff.number_field :weight, :required => true, step: 0.1, min: 0.0,
                  placeholder: '5.00', class: "form-control" %>
              </div>
          <!-- break -->                
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= ff.label :unit %><br>
                <%= ff.select :unit, QuoteMetal.units.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, k] }, {},
                class: "form-control", :required => true %>
            </div>
<% end %>
```

The lead model is writing to its datatable. What am I doing wrong causing the quote_metal not to write?

Comment: Please post your form code.

Comment: Try `<%= f.fields_for @quote_metal do |ff| %>` instead of `<%= f.fields_for 'quote_metal[]', @quote_metal do |ff| %>`.

Comment: Did my suggestion worked?

Comment: No. I need the brackets to allow the form to submit the information as an array. Submitting as an array allows for multiple of the quote_metal forms to be used.

Comment: Okay. Try `<%= f.fields_for 'quote_metals[]', @quote_metal do |ff| %>` Notice the **s** in `quote_metals`

Comment: Still the same unpermitted parameter

Comment: This one `<%= f.fields_for :quote_metals, @quote_metal do |ff| %>`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this line `<%= f.fields_for 'quote_metal[]', @quote_metal do |ff| %>`. It should be

```
<%= f.fields_for :quote_metals, @quote_metal do |ff| %>
```