# Nested parameter does not include <name>_attributes in Rails 4 when submitted nested attributes, has_many associated form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, strong-parameters

In my Rails app (v.4.2.6), when trying to nest the form for Questions in the form for Rounds, 
I am getting an Unpermitted parameter error. 

I can see that Rails is not converting my parameters from questions to questions_attributes.

I found this question, where the same thing is happening: 
[Unpermitted parameter in Rails 4 when submitted nested attributes, has_many associated form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388010/unpermitted-parameter-in-rails-4-when-submitted-nested-attributes-has-many-asso)

But modifying the line:

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions, @question do |builder| %>
```

did not resolve my issue.

Console Output (Params):

```
Processing by RoundsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oc5BHCv7pQzrKmcPG9x5nu+xMyOAJ/s09uiLakRrSLv6P5hND/xNKYn9qOyelSWK4MmqceZcdsESAWJ40coOgg==", "round"=>{"title"=>"Test", "questions"=>{"questiontext"=>"Q", "answertext"=>"A", "partialanswer"=>"", "difficulty"=>"", "pointval"=>"", "partialpoints"=>"", "notes"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Save Round"}
Unpermitted parameter: questions
```

Here is the code that I have:

Models:

```
class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :questions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, allow_destroy: true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :round
end
```

Round Controller:

```
class RoundsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @rounds = Round.all
    end

    def new
        @round = Round.new
        @round.questions.build
        @questions = Question.all 
        @question = Question.new 
    end

    def create
        @round = Round.new(round_params)
        if @round.save 
            redirect_to @round
        else 
            render 'new'
        end 

    end

    private
        def round_params
            params.require(:round).permit(:title, questions_attributes: [:id, :questiontext, :answertext])
        end


end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for :round, url: rounds_path do |f| %> 

<p> 
<%= f.label :title %> 
<%= f.text_area :title %> 
</p>

<H4> Add Questions to Round </H4>

    <%= f.fields_for :questions, @question do |builder| %>  

                <%= render "question_fields", :f => builder %>

    <% end %>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Partial:

```
<%= f.label :questiontext, "Question" %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :questiontext %><br/>

<%= f.label :answertext, "Answer" %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :answertext %><br/>
```

Please let me know if I can include any other details, or if there is anything that I can try, to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the nested_form_for helper method to enable the nesting.

your form will be,

```
<%= nested_form_for @round do |f| %>
```

Then use fields_for ,replace question with questions as round has many questions not question,

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions %>
```

Now in Your partials,

```
<%= f.label :questiontext, "Question" %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :questiontext %><br/>

<%= f.label :answertext, "Answer" %><br/>

<%= f.text_area :answertext %><br/>
```

Refer [nested form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form)

Comment: This works! It was important to change the form to <%= nested_form_for @round do |f| %> and to add the nested_form gem. In a previous project, I used nested forms and did not include the gem. Any clue why that worked and this didn't?

Comment: You might have used https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon gem in your previous project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <%= nested_form_for :round, url: rounds_path do |f| %>
```

as there is only `qustion` params it consider it as attribute of round object.`qustion_attibutes`

Comment: I tried this, but I got an error - undefined method `nested_form_for'.  Edit: Per Vedprakash's comment below it looks like I would need to add a gem for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your controller

```
class RoundsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @rounds = Round.all
  end

  def new
    @round = Round.new
  end

  def create
    @round = Round.new(round_params)
    @question = @round.questions.new(questiontext: params[:question][:questiontext], answertext: params[:question][:answertext])
    @question.save
    if @round.save 
        redirect_to @round
    else 
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def round_params
        params.require(:round).permit(:title, questions_attributes: [:id, :questiontext, :answertext])
    end
end
```

Now in your form

```
<%= form_for :round, url: rounds_path do |f| %> 

    <p> 
       <%= f.label :title %> 
       <%= f.text_area :title %> 
    </p>

    <H4> Add Questions to Round </H4>      

    <%= render "question_fields", locals: {:f => builder} %>

    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Now in your partial

```
<%= f.fields_for :question do |q| %> 
   <%= q.label :questiontext, "Question" %><br/>
   <%= q.text_area :questiontext %><br/>

   <%= q.label :answertext, "Answer" %><br/>
   <%= q.text_area :answertext %><br/>
<% end %>
```